# How to sample Bivariate Normal Distribution with Accept reject method

Tags: algorithms, probability-theory, probabilistic-algorithms, sampling

I have to write python code in jupyter due to sampling bivariate normal distribution with 3 sampling methods:

1. Prior Sampling
2. Gibbs Sampling
3. Rejection Sampling

I have done the first two samplings and I also have clear understanding of what accept reject method or so-called rejection sampling is.
yet I can not find any proposal distribution for it.

---

**Rejection Sampling and proposal distribution**

assume you have a distribution $f(x)$ which is not easy for you to sample.
choose another distribution that is easy for you to sample wisely called $g(x)$ so that for some constant $C$ for all $x$ we have $C.g(x) > f(x)$.

we call this $g(x)$ the proposal distribution.

sample from $g(x)$ and name it $X_i$ as you chose $g(x)$ because it was easy to sample. accept this sample with a probability of $p = f(X_i)/C.g(X_i)$.

As I said before I cant find any $g(x)$ easy enough to sample and yet bigger than bivariate normal distribution for some $C$.

Comment: Can you articulate a specific question?  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a concrete question.  I see only declarative sentences.  Note that coding is off-topic here, but algorithms and methods are on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this answer which can approximately sample a bivariate normal distribution with accept reject method and I thought it might be useful for others in future.

we choose a 2D uniform distribution called $F_{X,Y}(x,y) = F_X(x).F_Y(y)$ where both $X$ and $Y$ are uniform distributions in range of $(0, +a)$ and they are independent of each other.

We choose a constant $C$. Both $C$ and $a$ are chosen based on our bivariate normal distribution so that:

1. for all $x, y$ we have $C.F_{X,Y}(x,y) \geq BN(x,y)$, Where $BN$ is our bivariate normal distribution.
2. $x, y \in (-a, +a)$ supports most of our $BN$ density.

---

The Accept Reject Method:

1. Now we sample from our $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Suppose it's $X1 = (x1, y1)$.
2. We uniformly choose from:
   $$X_{1.1} = (x1, y1),$$
   $$X_{1.2}=(-x1, y1), $$
   $$X_{1.3}=(x1, -y1), $$
   $$X_{1.4} = (-x1, -y1)$$
   and name that $\hat{X_1}$ so that we consider all four quadrants of $xOy$.
3. Now we accept $\hat{X_1}$ as a sample of $BN$ with a probability of $p=BN(x1,y1)/C.f_{X,Y}(x,y)$.
4. We come back to step 1 and do this cycle to collect as much sample from the bivariate normal distribution as we want.